# All branches in if equation with non-parameter tests must have the same number of equations - Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I get an error on Modelica saying:

> All branches in if equation with non-parameter tests must have the same number of equations

The source of the error is following section of the code:

```
equation
  if der(Posit2.s)<=0 then
    pressure=4e5+((500e5-4e5)/0.0111)*(0.0111-Posit2.s);
  end if;
```

Do you know how to deal with this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an else, so the obvious idea is to say that pressure doesn't change:

```
 equation
    if der(Posit2.s)<=0 then
           pressure=4e5+((500e5-4e5)/0.0111)*(0.0111-Posit2.s);
    else
           der(pressure)=0;
    end if;
```

However, this will likely not compile due to the index-problem.
One possibility is to do manual index reduction and write something like:

```
 initial equation
    if der(Posit2.s)<=0 then
           pressure=4e5+((500e5-4e5)/0.0111)*(0.0111-Posit2.s);
    else
           pressure=4e5;
    end if;
 equation
    if der(Posit2.s)<=0 then
           der(pressure)=((500e5-4e5)/0.0111)*(-der(Posit2.s));
    else
           der(pressure)=0;
    end if;
```

Note that this equation has `der(pressure)=...*der(Posit2.s);` - due to the manual index reduction.

Comment: I implemented this code suggested by you. It throws no error when it compiles but gives an error when it calculates. Error is : Error encountered in the Initialite function of the user model.

Comment: You could try to replace the initial equation by something simpler like: initial equation pressure=4e5+((500e5-4e5)/0.0111)*(0.0111-Posit2.s); (without any if), or even initial equation pressure=4e5;